# OpenVPN fails to reconnect when network adapter reconnects to WiFi

Tags: openvpn

I'm using [pivpn](https://github.com/pivpn/pivpn/) to set up a VPN between my computer and an AWS instance. This is the autogenerated configuration file for the server (I've only changed the values of `keepalive`).

```
dev tun
proto udp
port 1194
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/issued/server_VzlgR4iTajic3eep.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/private/server_VzlgR4iTajic3eep.key
dh none
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "block-outside-dns"
push "redirect-gateway def1"
client-to-client
keepalive 10 60
remote-cert-tls client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-crypt /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ta.key
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/crl.pem
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log 20
status-version 3
syslog
verb 3
```

I have two issues.

### `keepalive` takes a long time to trigger a reconnect

As far as I understand the `keepalive 10 60` option triggers a `ping-restart` that sends a `SIGUSR1` to the process, to reconnect to the server. If I start openvpn on my client and I turn off and on the network interface, it takes up to 3 minutes to trigger a reconnect, while I would expect to happen in 60 seconds.

```
Wed May 29 01:26:50 2019 Initialization Sequence Completed
Wed May 29 01:29:54 2019 [server_VzlgR4iTajic3eep] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
```

### Reconnection hangs

If I trigger a reconnection with `SIGUSR1` or if I wait 3 minutes, the openvpn process stops at

```
Wed May 29 01:06:56 2019 Initialization Sequence Completed
Wed May 29 01:07:58 2019 [server_VzlgR4iTajic3eep] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Wed May 29 01:07:58 2019 SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
Wed May 29 01:07:58 2019 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
Wed May 29 01:08:03 2019 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]52.29.18.70:1194
Wed May 29 01:08:03 2019 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
Wed May 29 01:08:03 2019 UDP link local: (not bound)
Wed May 29 01:08:03 2019 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]xx.xx.xx.xx:1194
```

My guess is that the option `persist-tun` doesn't play well when a network interface disconnects (maybe a dependency between `tun` and `wlan0`). I tried to disable `persist-tun` on the client configuration, and it reconnects as expected. Even if this seems like a solution, I'd like to run my `openvpn` process as user `nobody`, but this setting doesn't allow to create a new `tun` interface.

```
Wed May 29 01:34:31 2019 ERROR: Cannot ioctl TUNSETIFF tun: Operation not permitted (errno=1)
Wed May 29 01:34:31 2019 Exiting due to fatal error
```

What I did at the end was to build a custom script to ping the VPN server, and trigger a `systemctl restart openvpn@pivpn` if the ping fails. To me, this seems the only reasonable approach if you want to start openvpn as `nobody`.

TL;DR: is there an *openvpn* way to reconnect without relying on a custom script? I'd like to rely only on `keepalive` but it seems to not work as expected. Also, I think there is no way to run openvpn as `nobody` and have permission to create a tunnel interface.